# Why do I get different results indexing with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is a simple example of trying to extract some rows
from a data.table, but what appear to be the same type
of logical vectors, I get different answers:

```
a <- data.table(a=1:10, b = 10:1)

a  # so here is the data we are working with

       a  b
   1:  1 10
   2:  2  9
   3:  3  8
   4:  4  7
   5:  5  6
   6:  6  5
   7:  7  4
   8:  8  3
   9:  9  2
  10: 10  1
```

let's extract just the first column since I need to dynamically
specify the column number as part of my processing

```
col <- 1L  # get column 1 ('a')

x <- a[[col]] > 5  # logical vector specifying condition
x
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
str(x)
   logi [1:10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
```

look at the structure of a[[col]] > 5

```
a[[col]] > 5
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
str(a[[col]] > 5)
   logi [1:10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
```

this looks very much like 'x', so why do these two different ways
of indexing 'a' give different results

```
a[x]  # using 'x' as the logical vector
      a b
  1:  6 5
  2:  7 4
  3:  8 3
  4:  9 2
  5: 10 1

a[a[[col]] > 5]  # using the expression as the logical vector
  Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
```

Comment: in `a[a[[col]] > 5]` `a[[col]]` is interpreted as column `a` not as data.table `a`. Avoid reusing names

Comment: nice catch.  I was just using some simple names and got caught.

Thanks

Comment: @DataMunger feel free to self answer or close the question. SO is knowledge base site and worth to maintain it so it can be more useful for future readers.